# android mapview problem

Tags: android, android-mapview

in my application i'm using map view which shows spots near my current location.if user click on map pushpin i'm showing detail information about that spot.for showing details ive used some animation part.

in that when user click on hide animation i want to again show the previous map .for showing the animation i've set the content view and again when user click on hide animation i'm calling the function from the main activity(from on create)

so when i call that function its giving me null pointer exception at mapview.
please help!!!

here is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //      searchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchId);
        //      searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //      nearestButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nearestId);
        //      nearestButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        url1=ongetUrl();
        new FetchTask(FindFishActivity.this, url1).execute(null);
    }

    private class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Context ctx;
        String str_url;

        public FetchTask(Context mcontext,String str) 
        {
            this.ctx=mcontext;
            this.str_url=str;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(FindFishActivity.this,"Loading Data","Please wait...");       
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
        {

            String res_str=onWebService(str_url);
            parse(res_str);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            onMapDisplay();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }


public void onMapDisplay() {
        String lakeNameString;
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

        mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
//      if(mapView==null)
//      {
//          MapView view=new MapView(FindFishActivity.this,"0pPZGIF27HwAISdkPQhUWYj12n5N63e-vAbun1g");
//          setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
//      }

        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapOverlays=mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable=FindFishActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin4);
        myOverlays=new MyOverlays(drawable,FindFishActivity.this);
        for(int i=0;i<latitude.size();i++)
        {
            if(!latitude.get(i).equals("")) 
            {
                lat=Double.parseDouble(latitude.get(i));
                latitudearr.add(lat);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<longitude.size();i++)
        {
            if(!longitude.get(i).equals(""))    
            {
                lon=Double.parseDouble(longitude.get(i));
                longitudearr.add(lon);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<lakeNameList.size();i++)
        {
            if(!lakeNameList.get(i).equals(""))
            {
                lakeNameString=lakeNameList.get(i);
            }

        }


        for(int k=0;k<latitudearr.size();k++)
        {
            startPoint=new GeoPoint((int)(latitudearr.get(k) * 1E6),(int)(longitudearr.get(k) * 1E6));

            mapController.animateTo(startPoint);
            overlayItem=new OverlayItem(startPoint, ""+lakeNameList.get(k).toString(),""+lDescription.toString());
            myOverlays.addOverlay(overlayItem);
            mapOverlays.add(myOverlays);
            mapController.setZoom(6);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }

    }
```

and for showing animation part

```
public void onShowInfo() {

                setContentView(R.layout.tutorial5);
//                  LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)FindFishActivity.this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//                  View c=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial5,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutID));

                    transparentPanel=(TransparentPanel)findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
                    transparentPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    transparentPanel.startAnimation(animShow);
                    final Button   hideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hide_popup_button);
                    hideButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            transparentPanel.startAnimation(animHide);
                            transparentPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String s=FindFishActivity.this.ongetUrl();
                            new FetchTask(FindFishActivity.this,s).execute(null);

                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is necessory for you to create separate layout ie. `tutorial5`.

There is other way round for you. In your `mapview` add relative layout and put `tutorial5` contents in that with transparancy and all that.

`Result:` You will get mapview with your `tutorial5` layout on top. Just hide it at beginning. when user clicks on pin just set visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and after clicking the stop revert it to  `View.GONE`.

With this map will still be active and you can navigate also when animation on top. Gives nice effect.

P.S: set your layout `tutorial5` background colour to `#80000000  i.e transparent black`. I personally like it.. :)